# C++ static_cast - safer way. why?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I have heard that static cast is a safer way to do casting.

Lets say that I have the following code:

```
int nValue = 48;
char ch = nValue;
```

This is implicit casting. But it is unsafe to change 4 bytes to 1 byte. If I will change this code to this:

```
int nValue = 48;
char ch = static_cast<char>(nValue);
```

It would be safer. why? what makes it safer? It is still changing 4 bytes to 1 byte.

Comment: It's not any safer to the computer but it's more explicit to anyone reading the source-code.

Comment: explicit casting is there to tell the compiler you know what you're doing. The compiler won't warn you because if you did it explicitly - its safe to assume you know the risk. I'm not sure if thats what you're asking, so I'll just leave a comment.

Comment: It's useful if you examine what "safer" means.  Since you "heard it somewhere" we don't really know what that word means to you.

Comment: If the casting is unsafe, then a standard cast will go without a warning, while a `static_cast` will issue a compilation error. The unsafety-ness is not visible in your example, but consider two different classes `A` and `B` (not related through inheritance or anything). Now, consider two pointers `A* a` and `B* b`. A standard cast such as `b = (B*)a` would go without a warning, although `b` would be very unsafe to use. A `static_cast` will yield a compilation error, preventing you from running your program until you've fixed it.

Comment: @Deduplicator The first example is perfectly valid. Narrowing implicit conversions are only an error in C++11 inside curly braces. Prior to C++11, and in C++11 outside of curly braces, they're allowed.

Comment: "But it is unsafe to change 4 bytes to 1 byte" - it's safe if you know that the value in the `int` is within the range of `char` !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `static_cast` is not safer than implicit conversion. However, you might have read that a `static_cast` is safer than a C cast. That's because it only allows "reasonable" casts. Some examples of a reasonable cast would be between numeric types, `void *` to some other pointer, base class ptr to derived class ptr. For example:

```
class Base {};
class D1 : public Base {};
class D11 {};
...
Base *ptr_to_Base(...); // Get from somewhere.
D11 *p = (D11 *) ptr_to_Base; // No compiler error! I need new eyeglasses!
D11 *p2 = static_cast<D11 *>(ptr_to_Base); // This gives you a compiler error.
```

Note that a `static_cast` can still allow bad casts, just not "unreasonable" ones:

```
class D2 : public Base {};
...
Base *b = new D2;
D1 *p3 = static_cast<D1 *>(b); // Wrong, but allowed by compiler.
```

Comment: You may show what is `ptr_to_Base`. And also avoid to mix `D1` and `Dl`.

Comment: @Jarod42: I'll edit to add `ptr_to_Base` definition. But I intentionally used two names that are easy to confuse, to help motivate the usage.

Comment: I agree with Jarod42.  It took me a couple of minutes to figure out how the pointer declarations were different.  The l and 1 are nearly identical that I couldn't figure out what you are trying to say.

Comment: @shawn1874: Okay, I guess being motivating is less important than being clear. I'll edit.

Comment: @shawn1874: Okay, now it's D11, which hopefully is clear, but a plausible typo that someone might make.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I'm prepared to suggest that the `static_cast` is *not* inherently safer. What the cast effectively does is tell the compiler to assume that the result will fit into the `char` and to not possibly warn you about data truncation. If you omit the cast, compilers are free to warn (especially if you request it) that data loss may be possible.

Not related to your question, but certainly related, `static_cast` *is* safer than both `reinterpret_cast` and C-style casts, because it has a much more limited set of legal conversions that it can perform.